# Why didn't Sarah tell Anne that Abigail had poisoned her?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-favourite

In *The Favourite* (2018), Before she took that ride on the horse, Sarah was poisoned by Abigail. The poison's effect showed on Sarah, who as a  result  fell on the ground and  was dragged by the horse. She returned to Anne late, lied to her that she had a battle on her way back instead of ever revealing to  her that she was poisoned by Abigail.

Why didn't Sarah tell Anne that Abigail had poisoned her?

Comment: Because you don't bother the queen with such petty infighting? Sure, there's verbal jabs etc., but those amuse Anne.